# conectar cliente mysql en wsl a host en windows

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, mysql-workbench, mysqlconnector

estoy tratando de conectarme a mi base de datos mysql desde wsl (el mismo código funciona en Windows), creo que es un error de configuración, pero soy nuevo en esto y no puedo resolverlo solo. aquí está mi código, estoy ejecutando mi código en el entorno python conda

```
-v3.7.11
-my.cnf on ubuntu is:
bind-address=Localhost
port=3306
-workbench config 
Hostname: Localhost
port=3306


import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
db = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="admin",
passwd="password",
database="database")
mycursor = db.cursor()


sql_select_Query = "SELECT * FROM table_name"
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
# get all records
records = cursor.fetchall()
records = pd.DataFrame(records)
print(records)
```

## Código de error:

**mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)**

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: hola pense que estaba publicando en el sitio en ingles, ya traduci, pido disculpas

Comment: Gracias por traducir la pregunta. ¿Te sale algún error en consola o en los logs de conda al correr este código? Si es así, por favor añádelo a la pregunta, editándola :)

Comment: Te sirve esta respuesta : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377052/how-to-connect-to-wsl-mysql-from-host-windows

Comment: Uno de los potenciales problemas que veo es `passwd="password",`. Según [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) debería ser `password="password",`.

Comment: gracias por las respuestas, acabo de editar la pregunta añadiendo el codigo de error. Asi mismo probe cambiar passwd="password" por password="password"  recibiendo el mismo error. el codigo al ejecutarlo fuera del wsl funciona correctamente

Comment: tambien revise el link de javier, el ip que tira ifconfig es  127.0.0.1, por lo que es el mismo en workbecnh de mysql y en el codigo que adjunte

Comment: @Ni0 entonces se soluciono?